# counting number of instances of certain class and acquiring values via Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, web-scraping, webdriverwait

I am trying to scrape data from [this website](https://www.ushl.com/view#/schedule/24/67/12/home?league=1&gametype=-1).

More specifically, I want my script to count the number of rows in the table and extract the attendance number from each line (refer to the image attached below.)[image]

Inspecting the website, I see the following for the date in the first row (Dec. 1):

```
<td ng-repeat="(k,h) in sec.headers track by $index" class="date ng-scope" data-high="false" data-hidden="false" 
ng-style="{'text-align':h.properties.align}" ng-bind-html="vals | getColData:[k]:language:seasonId" 
compile-table-col="" style="text-align: left;"><span>Dec. 1</span></td>
```

Then, I see the block of code for the crowd count in the first row (872)

```
<td ng-repeat="(k,h) in sec.headers track by $index" class="attendance ng-scope" data-high="false" 
data-hidden="false" ng-style="{'text-align':h.properties.align}" ng-bind-html="vals | getColData:[k]:language:seasonId" 
compile-table-col="" style="text-align: right;"><span>872</span></td>
```

I've tried multiple versions of `driver.find_elements_by_class_name` such as

```
elements = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("date ng-scope")
```

and

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//td[@class='date ng-scope']")))
```

Unfortunately, none of these worked.

Could someone point me in the right direction? If someone could offer advice on how to correctly count the number of rows by counting the number of instances of `'date ng-scope'` and extracting the corresponding crowd counts.

Comment: Do you 100% need all to be done in selenium? BeautifulSoup or even pandas_html might be easier.

Comment: @CeliusStingher No, but I was sort of pushed into using Selenium because I needed to choose options on drop-down menus and click buttons.  I would love to use BeautifulSoup but I would need to be able to update the address after having selected proper drop down menu items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it's a table, it's pretty easy to achieve as all you need to do is constantly increment the value of the table by 1. This is how I did it:

```python
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from time import sleep, strftime

url = "https://www.ushl.com/view#/schedule/24/67/12/home?league=1&gametype=-1"

webdriver = webdriver.Chrome()
webdriver.get(url)

x = 0
i = 2

while x == 0:
    try:
        date = webdriver.find_element_by_xpath(f"/html/body/div[5]/div[1]/div[4]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div/div/div/div/div/ng-view/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[{i}]/td[1]/span").text
        attendance = webdriver.find_elements_by_xpath(f"/html/body/div[5]/div[1]/div[4]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div/div/div/div/div/ng-view/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[{i}]/td[8]/span")[0].text

        print(f"Attendance Of {attendance} On Date {date}")
        i += 1
    except:
        x = 1
        break
```

Let me explain:

Line 1 - 3 import the necessary modules, such as selenium.

Line 4 sets the url to a string.

Line 5 defines the webdriver as Chrome.

Line 6 uses Chrome to open up the url we defined earlier on.

Line 7 defines x as 0. We need x to be 0 for the while loop later on.

Line 8 defines i as 2, which we need for the table later.

Line 9 initiates a while loop that will run as long as x is 0, which we set it to earlier on.

Line 10 starts a try command. You'll see why we need it later.

Line 11 sets date to the text of an xpath variable. I've used html before and so I roughly know how the table system works. tr stands for table row. The first date, Dec 1. is table row 2. We set i to 2 before, so we can use tr[{i}], to represent 2.

Line 12 does the exact same thing, but for attendance, still using i as it is a table. I added [0] at the end because the xpath for attendance was a list. Even though I'm pretty sure there is no list, selenium still thought so, so I decided to use [0] to get the first element of the list. There is no seconds or third element so [1] or [2] would not work.

Line 13 print the information for the user.
Line 14 increments i by 1 because in the next loop, we need to access the 3rd table row, so i += 1 sets i to 3.

We keep on running this until there are no more table rows left. When this happens, we use the try command on line 15 to break the while loop.

Comment: Thank you.  it does work but could you explain the syntax and the thought process? especially behind div[i].  I am having a hard time understanding what's going on.

Comment: I hope this helps

Comment: I think I am almost there.  I mainly had trouble understanding how you got all those div[i]s and I see that you did 'copy full Xpath.'  However, how did you know that you had to add `/span` to both lines?  Also, you said that you knew you had to add `[0]` for attendance because the xpath for attdendance was a list. Could you elaborate on this?  I tried `[1]` or different numbers to see what I would get and I learned that only `[0]` results in anything being printed.

Comment: Sorry, I realized that I was doing 'copy full Xpath' one line above where I should have. I still don't understand how you know you had to have `[0].`  Given that I can't even get `attendance = webdriver.find_elements_by_xpath(f"/html/body/div[5]/div[1]/div[4]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div/div/div/div/div/ng view/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[{i}]/td[8]/span").text` to print to see that it's a list, I would not have guessed the solution.

Comment: Does that help?

Comment: yes!  thanks. I actually tried `attendance = webdriver.find_elements_by_xpath(f"/html/body/div[5]/div[1]/div[4]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div/div/div/div/div/ng-view/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[{i}]/td[8]/span")[0]` and a few other versions to see what's going on.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Tables are lots of fun. I find it best to drill in from the outside rather than go right to the element you want first. For example, the number of rows.

```
driver.findElements("//div[contains(@class,'table-container')]//tr")
```

will return a list of elements, and getting the size of that list gets you the row count (this includes the header row, so if you want the actual number of games subtract 1). The xpath expression, translated, is "find any div element where the class name contains the string "table-container" and downstream of that, any tr elements"

The attendance field can be found with this xpath:

```
//div[contains(@class,'table-container')]//tr[2]/td[contains(@class,'attendance')]/span
```

where the tr[2] means the second row. Programatically, make that "[2]" a variable and substitute a loop index for 2 and iterate through the row count.

Answer (score 0):

Use `WebDriverWait()` and wait for `visibility_of_all_elements_located()` and use the following `css selector` to identify the number of **rows** and then iterate and finds the respective **columns**.

```
driver.get("https://www.ushl.com/view#/schedule/24/67/12/home?league=1&gametype=-1")
totalnoofrows=WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".resp >.ht-table >tbody >tr")))
for row in totalnoofrows[1:]:
    print("Date :" + row.find_element_by_xpath("./td[1]").text)
    print("Crowd :" + row.find_element_by_xpath("./td[8]").text)
    print("==============================================")
```

You need to import below libraries.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

---

**Console Output:**

```
Date :Dec. 1
Crowd :872
==============================================
Date :Dec. 14
Crowd :816
==============================================
Date :Dec. 15
Crowd :1065
==============================================
Date :Dec. 16
Crowd :497
=============================================
```